# Finding people with multiple activities

Tags: activities

We have a client who will be recording people who attend theatre productions. These attendances will be recorded as CRM activities (imported in bulk). The client would then like to search for people who have attended x activities (maybe over a set time period). Then group them and contact them.

CiviCRM would be very good at telling us who attended one or more theatre attendance activities. But not mutiple. Considered smart groups, custom searches, search builder, extended reports etc.

We think a custom extension may be needed for this. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Olly

Comment: depending on your CMS, a Drupal View may give you v much what you need

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the extension [summary fields](https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields) could be used as a base. Even though it probably does not do exactly what you want, it may be easier to build up on it insted of developing something completely new.

Or you could use the [SQL-Task Extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/sql-tasks-extension-configurable-recurring-tasks).

Comment: I was going to suggest adding this feature to Summary Fields - seems a great fit.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative with very little coding:

1. create a custom field on individual Number of Productions
2. create a CiviRule (trigger activity is added, condition activity type = xxxx)
3. develop a specific action to add 1 to the number of productions (max 2 hrs of work)
4. search on the custom field

Comment: Nice idea Erik. That provides a custom field they can search and react to (send mailings to those whit over 5 attendances in Wales etc). Big thanks

Comment: Anytime Olly :-)

Answer (score 1):

To me this sounds like a job for pivot tables:

1. Search - Find Activities.
2. Choose Export from the options dropdown.
3. Open the file in excel and make a pivot table, with the contact on the row, and count of activity id as the data value. Sort the pivot by count.

Comment: are pivot tables in core now - or still only via some Adv Report extension?

Comment: They're in Excel, and probably libreoffice. There is a type of pivot in the Extended Reports extension but it wouldn't solve this particular question.

Comment: apologies, i must have only read every other line in the above :-) but yes, some are in Extended Reports

Comment: No apology needed! If pivot tables were in core that would be awesome. They are my most used feature in excel. Well, maybe "fill down" is, but pivot tables second.